# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' but downloaded Requests

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip

I am trying to make a stat tracker for Fortnite and this is all I have so far.

```
import requests
headers = {'TRN-Api-Key': '<api-key>'}
url = 'https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/BKheang2003'
result = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
print(result.text)
```

However, whenever I run it, it gives the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`. I installed it using `pip install requests` and it said successfully installed. I am using the latest version of `pip` and `Python`. When it downloads, it says it downloads to this path in the command prompt. `c:\users\isaac\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages`. So to try and fix this, I added this to the search path in Visual Studio which is the IDE I am using. But, it says this path is not found which confused me because that's the path that is said requests was downloaded to. Can anybody help?

Comment: Did you post your actual API key?

Comment: Do you have Python 2 and 3 installed?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is in python3 but you installed requests for python2 imo. Try `pip3 install requests`. Since visual studio is an IDE, it has it's own tools integrated into it as well as it's own package manager. Try running the script from your terminal or try installing `requests` using visual studios' packages tab.
Refer docs :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 2):

try using `pip install requests --user`. The `--user` option helps to avoid environmental constraints. This of course in Windows. as for mac, the solution is simple too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you likely have several versions of python installed and are running the version with this code that does not have the requests module installed.

As you can see below, I used pip install to install requests, and that installed requests in my python2.7 path, so I can import the requests module there. However, when I use python3.6, I can not import requests - as the module has not been installed on my path.

```
~ python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Mar 22 2018, 15:04:47)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> exit()
~ python3
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 17 2017, 16:44:32)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Comment: So how do I download it for my version of Python

Comment: you can either use `pip2` to install for python 2.x or `pip3` to install for python 3.x as suggested above by Vedarth Sharma

Comment: @PokeBros did this work for you? If so, can you please select an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check if idna is installed.

This is because the **requests module** in python3 works along with idna. If it's not installed then, you can try **pip3 install idna**

for more on idna:
https://github.com/kjd/idna